# How to update an EOL Ubuntu distribution

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

I know that Ubuntu 11.10 has reached EOL status.  But is there a way to have it updated up until the EOL date of 5/9/2013?  I have looked at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release), and it talks about how to get it done, but when I go to old releases, 11.10 is not listed.

So is the fact that it just got EOL status it needs a little time to move there or is there another way to have that update done?

The system is too old to have anything above 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is wiser tyo do a fresh install of 12.04.2 or higher. 
There are advantages of doing a upgrade of 11.10 but in my eyes they are few compared to the disadvantages of any upgrade. 
Unity is growing up and has several new features under its skin, it would be sad for having problems with an upgrade that went wrong.

A fresh installation of a newer Ubuntu-version would be almost ideal for having a good working system without the polution of an older system upgraded.

You talk about **updating** but this is impossible with a version EOL.

So hit the download-button and do a fresh install ;)

Comment: The only problem is that the machine is old, and anything above 11.10, is a kill.  Plus I don't think it impossible to update.

Comment: Then, by far out, is using Xubuntu or even Lubuntu a better option than working with a EOL-version. Of course, if you like a Gnome-fork, using Mate as a desktop could solve your hardware-problem. But Unity as it is today is far to heavy to handle for older computers. So I'd give a go for Xubuntu 13.04